# Transform child is out of bounds (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

On my Hierarchy this is my [arrangement of gameobjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z82fn.jpg).

Here's my code of getting the MediaPlayer gameObject.

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject ump; // lets access the ump gameobject

 void Update()
{
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.MAKING_GAME_OBJECT == false)
    {
        //find the gameobject through getting the child of every component/gameobject
        ump = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).gameObject;
        if (ump != null) { 
        //Uses an If directives for the platform dependencies
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform = 2;
            if (ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform == 2)
            {
                Debug.Log("UMP property is set to Android");
                this.enabled = false;
            } else
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't set the property to Android");
            }
        #elif UNITY_STANDALONE
            ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform = 0;
            if(ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform == 0){
                Debug.Log("UMP property is set to StandAlone/Windows");
                this.enabled = false;
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't set the property to StandAlone/Windows");
            }
        #else
        #endif
        } else
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not get the gameobject UMP");
        }
```

Now it always throw me an error though I'm getting what actually i want.

Comment: This post was a miscount :)

Comment: Instead of chaining `GetChild()` it's safer to serialize the game object through the inspector. Either as `public` or `[SerializeField]`.

Comment: @Iggy I declared it already as serialized ? Or not?